# Different transactions must guarantedly select different items; avoid contentions

Tags: mysql, sql

As part of registering a new user; we assign them a resource (a Solr core, in this case) from a precompiled list (a table).

If 5 users sign up, they must be assigned 5 **different cores**; if the user successfully registers, the assignment is made final (see my depiction below).

But in real world, concurrently registering new users **contend for the same row, not choose different rows**. If X needs 5 seconds to register, Y and Z's registrations which are in X's "duration" will fail as they contend for the same row by X.

**Question:** How to make transactions choose without contentions, even under high concurrency such as 100 signups a second?

```
table: User
user_id   name  core   
      1    Amy h1-c1
      2    Anu h1-c1
      3    Raj h1-c1
      4    Ron h1-c2
      5    Jon h1-c2

table: FreeCoreSlots
core_id  core status   
      1 h1-c1   used
      2 h1-c1   used
      3 h1-c1   used
      4 h1-c2   used
      5 h1-c2   used #these went to above users already
      6 h1-c2   free
      7 h1-c2   free
      8 h1-c2   free
      9 h1-c2   free
```

Pseudo-code if stuff was isolated:

```
sql = SQLTransaction()
core_details = sql.get("select * from FreeCoreSlots limit 1")
sql.execute("update FreeCoreSlots set status = 'used' where id = {id}".format(
   id = core_details["id"]))
sql.execute("insert into users (name,core) values ({name},{core})".format(
   name = name,
   id   = core_details["id"]))
sql.commit()
```

---

If 100 signups happen a second, they would **contend for the first row** in `FreeCoreSlots` and cause serious fails.

There is a select... for update as in [InnoDB SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement locking all rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690458/innodb-select-for-update-statement-locking-all-rows-in-a-table) as the solution, but they seem to suggest lowering the isolation. Is this method the right way?

Comment: I think this example does what you want using a stored procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/562744/1584772.  At least, it is a good place to start (the key is making this all happen in one transaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question I would ask is why it could take 5 seconds for a user to complete. Between the `START TRANSACTION` and the `COMMIT` should be only fractions of a second.

To prevent that you assign the same row in `FreeCoreSlots` to the same use another time you must use `SELECT for UPDATE`. The lock level is not really the problem in my opinion. The way you designed the database the next free row in `FreeCoreSlots` is actually locked until the transaction is done. See my test results below. And I do think that even for 100 new users per second it should still be sufficient. But if you even want to overcome this you must find a way to lock another next free row in `FreeCoreSlots` to every user. Unfortunately there is no function of "Select first row unless it has a lock". Maybe instead use some random or modulus logic. But as I said already I think that should not be your problem even for the unthinkable amount of 100 new users per second. If I err with this feel free to leave a comment and I am willing to have another look at it.

Here is my test result. Default InnoDB lock level: **repeatable read** without `FOR UPDATE`. This way it does NOT work.

```
User 1:
    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT * FROM FreeCoreSlots WHERE status = 'FREE' LIMIT 1 -- returns id 1
User 2:
    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT * FROM FreeCoreSlots WHERE status = 'FREE' LIMIT 1 -- also returns id 1 !!!
User 1:
    UPDATE FreeCoreSlots SET status = 'USED' where ID = 1;
User 2:
    UPDATE FreeCoreSlots SET status = 'USED' where ID = 1; -- WAITS !!!
User 1:
    INSERT INTO user VALUES (...
    COMMIT;
USER 2:
    wait ends and updates also ID = 1 which is WRONG
```

Lock level **repeatable read** but with `FOR UPDATE`. This way it does WORK.

```
User 1:
    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT * FROM FreeCoreSlots WHERE status = 'FREE' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE -- returns id 1
User 2:
    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT * FROM FreeCoreSlots WHERE status = 'FREE' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE -- WAITS
User 1:
    UPDATE FreeCoreSlots SET status = 'USED' where ID = 1;
User 2:
    still waits
User 1:
    INSERT INTO user VALUES (...
    COMMIT;
USER 2:
    Gets back Id 2 from the select as the next free Id
```

Comment: 5 seconds was a 10x exaggeration anyway :-) I however got it to work in spite of waits by setting a read uncommitted isolation and `select a (select a free row as subquery) for update` which is kinda above my head. But your method is simpler to "do" in SQLAlchemy ORM.

Answer (score 5):

By setting the transaction isolation level to serializable.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Effectively, this blocks other transactions from altering the updated table while the transcation processes, ensuring that your data is updated in atomic, consistent fashion.

Comment: please explain this too. Im refering this now but I dont get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Defer the assignment until the last possible moment. Don't try to bind it up during the registration process.

Leverage the status column as a concurrency tactic. Apply a predicate that ensures that you will only update the row if it is still 'free'. With the default isolation level, the read will be non-blocking. Your update will either update 1 row or none. You can loop if not successful, and place a limit on the number of tries (in case the free slots are exhausted). You could also pre-fetch more than 1 free id, to save on round trips on your attempts. Lastly, this would be better as a stored procedure that returns the id of the newly-allocated slot. In that case, you employ a similar tactic in your stored procedure, where you fetch/update until your update is successful. In high-contention environments, I have selected a random row from the top N free ones, if serial assignment is not very important.

```
sql = SQLTransaction()

core_details = sql.get("select * from FreeCoreSlots where status = 'free' limit 1")
sql.execute("update FreeCoreSlots set status = 'used' where id = {id} and status = 'free'".format(
   id = core_details["id"]))

//CHECK ROW COUNT HERE (I don't know what language or library you are using.
//Perhaps sql.execute returns the number of rows affected).
//REPEAT IF ROW COUNT < 1

sql.execute("insert into users (name,core) values ({name},{core})".format(
   name = name,
   id   = core_details["id"]))
sql.commit()
```